# How to put text in a select class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am trying to put text into a select class.

Here is the following code;

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">        
<select class="form-control col-l10 col-m7 col-s7 esw-select ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-class="{'is-invalid': shipping_subform.$submitted &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.shippingRegion.$invalid}" id="Shipping_Territory" required="" ng-options="region.code  as region.name for region in regions" ng-model="userOrder.Shipping.Address.Region" name="shippingRegion" tooltip="Please select a province" tooltip-toggle=" shipping_subform.$submitted===true &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.shippingRegion.$invalid===true" esw-google-analytics-blur="">

<option value="" class="ng-binding">Select a province</option>
<option value="0" label="Ontario">Ontario</option>
<option value="1" label="British Columbia">British Columbia</option><option value="2" label="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
<option value="3" label="Alberta">Alberta</option>
<option value="4" label="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
<option value="5" label="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
<option value="6" label="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
<option value="7" label="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option><option value="8" label="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
<option value="9" label="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
<option value="10" label="Quebec">Quebec</option>
<option value="11" label="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
<option value="12" label="Yukon">Yukon</option>
</select>        <!-- ngIf: shipping_subform.$submitted && shipping_subform.shippingRegion.$invalid -->    
</div>
```

I have tried the following which works; however, when I click the submit button, it says to please select a province.

This works but it doesn't actually work when clicking the submit button;

```
document.querySelector('#Shipping_Territory [label= Ontario]').selected = true;
```

Supposedly I have to use angular, but I don't know what to put in the  triggerHandler.

```
 var e = document.getElementById("Shipping_Territory");
  e.value = "Ontario";
  var $e = angular.element(e);
  $e.triggerHandler('??');
```

I have tried in the triggerHandler, change, changed, select, selected, but it just turns the select dropdown to blank.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to  tag

```
<select id="selectedOption" class="form-control col-l10 col-m7 col-s7 esw-select ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-class="{'is-invalid': shipping_subform.$submitted &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.shippingRegion.$invalid}" id="Shipping_Territory" required="" ng-options="region.code  as region.name for region in regions" ng-model="userOrder.Shipping.Address.Region" name="shippingRegion" tooltip="Please select a province" tooltip-toggle=" shipping_subform.$submitted===true &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.shippingRegion.$invalid===true" esw-google-analytics-blur="">
```

And get index of selectedOption using:-

```
document.getElementById("selectedOption").options.selectedIndex
```

i hope it helps!

Comment: This doesnt help, I think I got to do it the angular way. Also how would I enter the text, all yours does is get the index.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following with success;

```
var e = document.getElementById("Shipping_Territory");
  e.value = 2;
  var $e = angular.element(e);
  $e.triggerHandler('change');
```